# Simple number cipher to obfuscate IDs

Tags: encryption

I want to obfuscate my ids in me webapp.

So I need to change
`f(id) = hidden_id`
with easily accessible `f-1(hidden_id) = id`.

Security is not a big deal, but it would be nice if `f` is not obvious (like `f(x) = ax + b`). A good signal to achieve this would be that `a < b => f(a) < f(b)` is not true.

My basic knowledge is crypto tells me I should look at something like `f(x) = x^a % b` but I haven't found my way through this until now.

I thought that was a simple question!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing those functions (did the XOR trick suggested by @Niels2000)

In Ruby:

```
  def self.encrypt(id)
    # Concat [1] because first number IS a 0 hence information is lost
    ([1] + id.to_s(2).split('').reverse.map{ |b| 1 - b.to_i}).join('').to_i(2)
  end

  def self.decrypt(encrypted_id)
    # Remove the [1]
    (encrypted_id.to_s(2).split('').map{ |b| 1 - b.to_i}).join('')[1..-1].reverse.to_i(2)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any fast block cipher (AES or even old DES) with a random fixed key. It is not cryptographically secure, but it has all the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to talk about encryption and xor, but maybe what you really need is to just use random ids. It depends on what it is you're trying to defend against.

Comment: IDs are there, I can't change them.

Comment: You could map them, though. As in, generate random ids and map them to the real ids in a simple table:

Comment: Example:

id map
100 5900c7c1bc1c
101 c2ab53a2ff2c
102 0f50b8d3c233

Etc. Then mask then going out and map them going in. Et voila!